# React--Div exists, but is empty & more problems

Tags: json, reactjs, map-function

I'm using the code below to pull in a list of data from a JSON file in order to populate a webpage with `News`. However, with what I have, the div is empty when I inspect it, and I'm not sure why. When I attempt other solutions, I get errors or the same output.

```js
const newsList = labNewsJson['news']

class News extends Component {
  render() {
    const news = newsList.map((newsItem) => {
      <div>{newsItem}</div>
    });

    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <h1>Lab News</h1>
        <div>{news}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default News;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a return to your map function.

```
const news = newsList.map((newsItem, index) => {
  return <div key={index}>{newsItem.title}</div>
});
```

Comment: Or remove the `{}` : `const news = newsList.map(newsItem => <div>{newsItem}</div>)`. But also he's missing a `key` on the div

Comment: I did that and that's when I got errors. It returns, "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title, description}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead."

Comment: Then newsItem is an object, and you should only be accessing specific properties, ex: return <div>{newsItem.title}</div>

Comment: I've updated the answer and included mpen's recommendation of using a key.

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked :D  Could you explain what the <div key={index}> is doing?

Comment: Normally you'd try and avoid using just the index like I did as the key in case the order of items changes, but it's a way to help keep your elements unique, which in turn helps React keep track of them. You can read more in the docs https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Answer (score 0):

When you are using {}, map function does not return anything. You have two options:

1- Try to use () instead of {}:

```
const news = newsList.map((newsItem) => (
    <div>{newsItem}</div>
))
```

2- Return the item in every iteration:

```
const news = newsList.map((newsItem) => {
    return <div>{newsItem}</div>
})
```